# When exporting shapefile I added polygons to I get an error

Tags: polygon, geometry, error, polygon-creation

I was tasked with updating a map at work and had to add a number of polygons to the layout. I did this by creating features and then just selecting polygon or autocomplete polygon and just drawing them in. I then had to just match the attributes of the new polygon to some nearby ones.

Nothing too complicated. However, when I try to export the new shapefile I get the following errors in order of pop up windows.

First

```
Error exporting data. The parameter is (or has an element that is) the wrong kind of geometry
```

Second

```
Warning: Some records may not have been exported correctly.
```

Third

```
There was an error exporting the layer.
```

The shapefile is still created, but when adding it to the map it seems like it only exports the shapefiles that already existed before my edits.

I ran the Check Geometry Tool afterwards and the table it returns tells me under the Problem Field that there are self-intersections and empty Z values.

I am able to easily see which ones I created because they have 0 as ObjectID. Is this part of the issue?

Is there any easy way to remove self-intersections and empty z values without deleting all of my work creating and measuring out the new polygons?

Comment: is it a line or point shapefile? Shapefiles can only have one type of geometry in them.

Comment: They are all polygons made up of lines. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the release of ArcGIS in use and whether any patches have bee applied.